# Differences between volatile and atomic

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, atomic

```
int value = 0;
volatile boolean done = false;

// Thread A:
value = 1; done = true;

// Thread B:
if (done) System.out.println(value);
```

This is fine, since done is defined as volatile.

What about the same code, except that done is defined as an AtomicBoolean - does it achieve the same effect?  In other words, do atomic (RMW) operations, apart from being atomic and visible, also guarantee that all previous write are flushed to shared memory?

```
int value = 0;
AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

// Thread A:
value = 1; done.set(true);

// Thread B:
if (done.get()) System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: The AtomicBoolean is build on top of a volatile field. So the get is a volatile read and the set a volatile write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Javadoc of `java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html):

> The memory effects for accesses and updates of atomics generally follow the rules for volatiles, as stated in The Java Language Specification (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> - get has the memory effects of reading a volatile variable.
> - set has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable.
> - ...

So in this case, there is no difference between `volatile` and `AtomicBoolean`.